# Framework7 + Vue: Trying to dynamically align columns; adjustments don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, html-framework-7

In F7Vue, columns should be automatically spaced if the :width attribute isn't set.

I have a set of columns I generate with a Vue loop.  Relative to itset, each column's spacing looks good.  But relative to one another, my rows look messy, since certain rows have columns that require a lot of room.

```
            <f7-card-content >
            <f7-list style="background: white; color: black">
                <f7-list-item v-for="result in orderedSubcategory" @click="openKKS(result.kks)" class="popup-trigger">
                    <f7-col>{{ getNumber(result.kks) }}</f7-col>
                    <f7-col>{{ result.hersteller }}</f7-col>                                    
                    <f7-col>{{ result.typ }}</f7-col>
                    <f7-col>{{ result.artikelNummer }}</f7-col>
                </f7-list-item>
            </f7-list>
            </f7-card-content>
```

To solve this, I wrote a computed function to get the max width of each row, so that theoretically the columns should all begin at the same points.  Yet, when I run this, the columns look exactly the same - automatic spacing.

```
            <f7-card-content >
            <f7-list style="background: white; color: black">
                <f7-list-item v-for="result in orderedSubcategory" @click="openKKS(result.kks)" class="popup-trigger">
                    <f7-col :width="getKksWidth">{{ getNumber(result.kks) }}</f7-col>
                    <f7-col :width="getHerstellerWidth">{{ result.hersteller }}</f7-col>                                    
                    <f7-col :width="getTypWidth">{{ result.typ }}</f7-col>
                    <f7-col :width="getArtikelWidth">{{ result.artikelNummer }}</f7-col>
                </f7-list-item>
            </f7-list>
            </f7-card-content>
```

This is the result, before and after:
[image]

So even when I set the computed width, the spacing doesn't change.  What's strange is that the element inspector shows the widths are being set:

[image]

Each `list-item` element has identical widths for the columns.  Why isn't each column starting at the same point on the horizontal axis in my result?

As per Oluwafemi Sule's suggestion, here's the result when I hard code the widths (it's the same -- they're set automatically)

[image]

Comment: Can you try using column widths should sum up to 100%? Maybe hard-set to 20, 20 30, 30 and see if you have a different result.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule   I tried that out and added the results to the post

Comment: Looks the same to me. Ideally, `col`s should be contained in `rows` and usually some frameworks do care for whether `col` are directly descendent from `rows`. It could be a thing that the property rules are not effected with your current structure. Try wrapping all `col` in a `row` and `card-content` in a `col` if it currently isn't.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule  In F7+Vue the row construct is <f7-grid>, which should contain contain the columns.  When I wrap the columns in this, the padding is completely messed up.  I suspect it doesn't work inside of list-items (which I definitely must have)